# Django - Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable and convert to model data in views

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, decimal

```
rows = fetchall()
resultList = []
resultModel = []
resultDict = []
for row in rows:
    resultModel.append(ResultModel(*row)) # Object of type ResultModel is not JSON serializable
    resultList.append(list(row)) # Rows returned by pyodbc are not JSON serializable
    resultDict.append(dict(zip(columns, row))) # Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable
```

I need to get a json version of the data in the view. For this, I am trying to get the JSON dump of the data.
Using  `json.dumps(resultDict)` throws the error.

The errors trying different results from the model is commented out for reference. 
The `dict(zip())` option is the closest to what I want resultDict gives me a JSON (key, value) pairing that I can use. But it gives me an error on the resulting data that includes '`DecimalField`' Is there a way to have decimal places without erroring on the data returned back? It seems that this would be a simple thing Django would support, so I'm not sure if I am missing something!

https://github.com/pyeve/eve-sqlalchemy/issues/50

Also, can I process the ResultModel directly into the json dump in the view, rather than setting up 2 result sets (of the same data, just different formatting) to send back to the view from the model?

**UPDATE**: I figured this out. As this is a stored proc/direct query, ORM mapping doesn't work when we use 
`dict(zip(columns, row))` , the column names from the db query should be used. Then, for getting JSON do a `json.dumps(myDict)`

Alternate solution: 
In models, `return [ResultModel(*row) for row in rows]`

Views:

```
results = Get-model
json = serializers.serialize("python", results, fields=('Column1', 'Column2')
```

But this also gives me the model name. Is there a way to get only the .fields part of each list returned?

[
fields: {Column1: "1", Column2: "2"},
model:"app_name.resultmodel",
pk:""
]

Comment: Indeed, JSON does not have a decimal type so json.dumps does not know what to do with your DecimalField. But Django **does** support this, in its serializers which are intended for exactly this. Or, use Django REST Framework which has much more customisable ones.

Comment: I got this working by using - ```from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder```and then ```json.dumps(data, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)``` but I have had to return both the ResultModel as well as the JSON version. I need both, is there a way to send one in and then covert it in the views/templates as needed?

Comment: Also, is the serializer supposed to be seperated our from the views.py ? Am very new to using Django so want to try and use best practises

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try to extend the JSONEncoder

```
import json
from decimal import Decimal

class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Decimal):
            return float(obj)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

# Usage:
d = Decimal("42.5")
json.dumps(d, cls=DecimalEncoder)
```

Comment: edited my question. I have 2 objects that I create and send in to the view, from the model. Is there a way to display the model data (ResultModel (row)) from the json object/dictionary of columns? ```{'col1': 'val1', 'col2':'val2'} {'col1':'res2', 'col2':'row2'}``` but this is not an array/list of objects so the looping over doesn't work in the template directly. Trying to use ```json.loads(jsonData)``` doesn't work either.